# std::tuple data member in a concept

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, stdtuple

Continuing my studies in C++ concepts, I would like to define a `std::tuple<t...>` data member in a `concept`.

In the following code:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept c1 = requires(t p_t) {
  { p_t.i } -> std::same_as<int &>;
};

template <typename t, typename... c1>
concept c3 = requires(t p_t) {
  { p_t.cs } -> std::same_as<std::tuple<c1...> &>; // ERROR 1
};

template <c1... t_c1> struct a1 { std::tuple<t_c1...> cs; };

struct a2 {
  int i{-9};
};

struct a3 {
  int i{8};
};

void f(c3 auto &p_c3) { std::cout << std::get<0>(p_c3.cs).i << std::endl; } // ERROR 2

int main() {

  a1<a2, a3> _a;

  f(_a);  // ERROR 3

  return 0;
}
```

But there are errors:

`ERROR 1` (the cause of the other errors)

```
main.cpp:12:17: Because type constraint 'std::same_as<std::tuple<a2, a3> &, std::tuple<> &>' was not satisfied:
main.cpp:31:3: Because type constraint 'std::same_as<std::tuple<a2, a3> &, std::tuple<> &>' was not satisfied:
```

`ERROR 2`:

```
main.cpp:25:8: Because 'a1<a2, a3>' does not satisfy 'c3'
main.cpp:31:3: Because 'a1<a2, a3>' does not satisfy 'c3'
```

`ERROR 3`:

```
main.cpp:31:3: No matching function for call to 'f'
main.cpp:25:6: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with p_c3:auto = a1<a2, a3>]
main.cpp:25:8: because 'a1<a2, a3>' does not satisfy 'c3'
main.cpp:12:17: because type constraint 'std::same_as<std::tuple<a2, a3> &, std::tuple<> &>' was not satisfied:
/usr/include/c++/11/concepts:63:9: note: because '__detail::__same_as<std::tuple<a2, a3> &, std::tuple<> &>' evaluated to false
/usr/include/c++/11/concepts:57:27: note: because 'std::is_same_v<std::tuple<a2, a3> &, std::tuple<> &>' evaluated to false
```

If I change the line `{ p_t.cs } -> std::same_as<std::tuple<c1...> &>;` to `{ p_t.cs };` the errors disappear.

So, what is the correct way to define a `std::tuple` data member in a `concept`?

Comment: Regardless of correctness, naming things `c1` and `c2` and the like obscures what your code is intended to do.  Code both communicates with the compiler, and with other programmers, including yourself (present and future).  Here you are asking other programmers to read and understand your code: make an effort to make your code easy to understand.  Give variables, concepts, functions and types names that describe what they are.

Comment: I was sure everyone would immediately understand that my intention with the example was not to describe a real situation, but actually to show a doubt on how to use a language feature. It seems I assumed wrongly.

Comment: Sure, but there is no need for `c1` to be `c1` and not `is_int_reference`.  99% of the population find meaningful names easier to remember than random letter number combinations.  Sometimes convention leads to specific short names being known, but not here.

Comment: `c1` could be anything because its meaning is irrelevant, as the question is about the `std::tuple` in `c3`.

Comment: Yes, and `c1` and `c3` are equally meaningless, despite having indistinguishable names.  Anyhow, feel free to ignore my advice, and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concepts there is no deduction of the type parameters, so given a parameter of type `T` passed to `f` the concept the compiler is checking is `c3<T>`, but for a parameter of type `a1<a2, a3>` the concept that would apply would be `c3<T, a2, a3>`, i.e. the function signature would need to be

```
void f(c3<a2, a3> auto &p_c3);
```

Note that for actually implementing something like `c3`, you'd need to deduce the template parameters which requires to be able to check them against `c1`, so you'd need to basically go with pre-concept strategies for this:

```
// helper to enforce IsC1TupleHelper is only used in an unevaluated context
template<class ...Ts>
constexpr bool AlwaysFalse = false;

// helper function for deducing the template parameters of std::tuple
template<c1 ... Ts>
std::true_type IsC1TupleHelper(std::tuple<Ts...>const&)
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<Ts...>, "IsC1TupleHelper is only allowed to be used in an unevaluated context");
}

// helper function fallback for types other than tuples of c1
template<class T>
std::false_type IsC1TupleHelper(T const&)
{
    static_assert(AlwaysFalse<T>, "IsC1TupleHelper is only allowed to be used in an unevaluated context");
}

// c3 with a better(?) name
template<class T>
concept CsMemberIsTupleOfC1 = requires(T t)
{
    { IsC1TupleHelper(t.cs) } -> std::same_as<std::true_type>;
};

void f(CsMemberIsTupleOfC1 auto& p_c3)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(p_c3.cs).i << std::endl;
}
```

You need to be aware though that this concept won't prevent the user from passing a parameter of a type to `f` that results in a compiler error, e.g.

```
a1<> _a2;
f(_a2);
```

fails compilation of the specialization of `f`, since you try to access the first element of a tuple that doesn't have any elements using `std::get<0>`.

You the following implementation of `c3` would probably be more suitable and wouldn't require deducing the type parameters of the tuple:

```
// checks if the first element type of the tuple matches c1
template<class T>
concept FirstTupleElementIsC1 = c1<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>>;

template <typename T>
concept c3 = requires(T p_t) {
    { p_t.cs } -> FirstTupleElementIsC1;
};
```

or

```
template <typename T>
concept c3 = requires(T p_t) {
    { std::get<0>(p_t.cs) } -> c1;
};
```

Comment: I think your second suggestion will do the work. I will try it and get back to you as soon as possible.

In time, `f` would not actually call `std::get<0>(p_c3.cs)`, but some kind of traverse would be performed on `p_c3.cs`, limited by `p_c3.cs.size()`

Answer (score 0):

The function call `f` results in the type substitution `c3<a1<a2, a3>>` to be applied to the concept `c3`. This results in the `typename... c1` parameter pack to be nil. This will always be the case when a single type is applied to `c3` and, thus, `std::same_as` will return false.

Therefore, the only possible call to `f` that satisfies the concept `c3` is something like the following that contains an empty tuple type:

```
struct a4 { std::tuple<> cs; };
a4 b;
f(b);
```

However, in this case, then the body of `f` will have an error when you attempt the `std::get<0>` on an empty tuple type.

Thus, as far as I can tell, there is no possible call to `f` on any type that will compile.

If you could explain the intention behind the concept `c3`, maybe I could give you a more informative answer.

Comment: `c3` is a communication channel and `c1` is responsible for serialize events (structs that will be handled by other classes) into messages (byte array), and to deserialize messages into events. `c1` could be an abstract class, but I would like the message that incomes or outgoes through the channel to be size fixed (`std::array`) or size variable (`std::vector` or `std::string`).

I hope this short description helps to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian), that was the best solution I could think of so far:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename t>
concept c1 = requires(t p_t) {
  { p_t.i } -> std::same_as<int &>;
};

template <typename t>
concept c3 = requires(t p_t) {
  {p_t.cs};
  requires c1<std::tuple_element_t<0, decltype(p_t.cs)>>;
};

template <c1... t_c1> struct a1 { std::tuple<t_c1...> cs; };

struct a2 {
  int i{-9};
};

struct a3 {
  int i{8};
};


void f(c3 auto &p_c3) { std::cout << std::get<0>(p_c3.cs).i << std::endl; }


int main() {

  a1<a2, a3> _a;

  f(_a);

  return 0;
}
```